# Set mysql user rights with plesk

Tags: mysql

With Plesk (v. 10.2.0) I can create multiple user accounts for a MySQL database. I however seem not to find a way to restrict one of the user accounts to read only access. The created users do not have the right to execute GRANT / REVOKE.

Am I supposed to use the root database access account for this which Plesk supposedly uses to create the users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to tune in MySQL database. 
You can do it in shell or via embedded DB manager (phpMyAdmin).

For tuning in Linux shell run

```
 mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysql
```

I think you would need to tune content of `user` and `db` tables, but the best would be to refer to original MySQL documentation.

For DB manager, go to Server > Databases > click icon right to local MySQL database (be sure you don't block pop-ups as phpMyAdmin will open in a new window). Then you can open any database in left menu and if you choose privileges tab, you can tune users access.

Comment: Yes, the last paragraph in this answer is very important!!  In my Plesk it was `Server > Database Servers > The spanner icon on the 'MySQL' row` then I clicked on any database and chose privileges and there it was.